# the PostgreSQL engine does not support Windows

Tags: postgresql, go, sqlc

I try to generate golang code using sqlc package but it say "the PostgreSQL engine does not support Windows"
I tried to generate code for insert operation in postgresql for which I used postgresql alpine docker image.

my sql.yaml file is

```
version: "1"
packages:
  - name: "db"
    path: "./db/sqlc"
    queries: "./db/query/"
    schema: "./db/migration/"
    engine: "postgresql"
    emit_json_tags: true
    emit_prepared_queries: false
    emit_interface: false
    emit_exact_table_names: false
```

account.sql

```
-- name CreateAccount: one
INSERT INTO accounts (
    owner,
    balance,
    currency
) VALUES(
    $1,$2,$3
) RETURNING *;
```

and my scema contain

```
CREATE TABLE "accounts" (
  "id" bigserial PRIMARY KEY,
  "owner" varchar NOT NULL,
  "balance" bigint NOT NULL,
  "currency" varchar NOT NULL,
  "created_at" timestamptz NOT NULL DEFAULT (now())
);

CREATE TABLE "entries" (
  "id" bigserial PRIMARY KEY,
  "account_id" bigint NOT NULL,
  "amount" bigint NOT NULL,
  "created_at" timestamptz NOT NULL DEFAULT (now())
);

CREATE TABLE "transfers" (
  "id" bigserial PRIMARY KEY,
  "from_account_id" bigint NOT NULL,
  "to_account_id" bigint NOT NULL,
  "amount" bigint NOT NULL,
  "created_at" timestamptz NOT NULL DEFAULT (now())
);

ALTER TABLE "entries" ADD FOREIGN KEY ("account_id") REFERENCES "accounts" ("id");

ALTER TABLE "transfers" ADD FOREIGN KEY ("from_account_id") REFERENCES "accounts" ("id");

ALTER TABLE "transfers" ADD FOREIGN KEY ("to_account_id") REFERENCES "accounts" ("id");

CREATE INDEX ON "accounts" ("owner");
```

What I am missing?[image]

Comment: See  [Support the PostgreSQL engine on Windows #282](https://github.com/kyleconroy/sqlc/issues/282).

Answer (score 2):

Regarding [#282](https://github.com/kyleconroy/sqlc/issues/282) sqlc doesn't support PostgreSQL for windows. But you can generate files using docker, as mentioned in the installation guide of sqlc.([link](https://docs.sqlc.dev/en/stable/overview/install.html))

> docker run --rm -v $(shell pwd):/src -w /src kjconroy/sqlc generate

Comment: The official Docker image has moved to the sqlc organization. You'll want to do `docker pull sqlc/sqlc` instead.

Answer (score -1):

1. First pull the docker image for sqlc in cmd make sure docker is running and execute the command `docker pull kjconroy/sqlc`
2. Open the project directory in PowerShell and run the command
   `docker run --rm -v ${PWD}:/src -w /src kjconroy/sqlc generate` This should work fine.

Answer (score -3):

for PowerShell use `docker run --rm -v ${PWD}:/src -w /src kjconroy/sqlc generate`